# How to select only two rows for each distinct element in a colum (PostgreSQL 9.3.5)

Tags: postgresql

Right now I have a query that looks like this. The `%s` is for psycopg2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p1.creating_user_id) p1.post_id, p1.message
    FROM posts p1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN post_relations pr1 ON pr1.post_id=p1.post_id AND pr1.receiving_user_id=%s
    WHERE p1.creating_user_id IN (SELECT ur2.user_b_id 
        FROM user_relations AS ur2 
        WHERE ur2.user_a_id=%s 
        AND ur2.friend=true)
    ORDER BY p1.creating_user_id, p1.created_utc DESC
```

How would I alter this query to return two rows for reach creating_user_id as opposed to only one row? Is there a way to do it while still using `SELECT DISTINCT` or do I have to do some sort of subquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) can do it

```
select post_id, message
from (
    select
        p1.post_id, p1.message,
        row_number() over(
            partition by p1.creating_user_id
            order by p1.created_utc desc
        ) as rn
    from
        posts p1
        left outer join
        post_relations pr1 on pr1.post_id = p1.post_id and pr1.receiving_user_id = %s
    where p1.creating_user_id in (
        select user_b_id 
        from user_relations
        where user_a_id = %s and friend = true
    )
) s
where rn <= 2
```